# Blower.io - Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

When I run the test command from the website:

```
curl -X POST -d "to=+14155550000&message=This is a test from Blower.io" -H "Accept: application/json" [MY_URL]/messages
```

I receive this error:

> The From phone number +3153811354 is not a valid, SMS-capable inbound
>   phone number or short code for your account.

Anyone else seeing this?

Comment: The copyright notice on blower.io is from 2013–2015. Are you sure it's still being maintained?

Comment: An email to the support address got a response and a fix to my account pretty quickly. That's concerning about the copyright, however.

Comment: Last update: asked support email about status. Response: "It’s been about 6 years so far. No plans to stop yet "